# Backbone/underscore.js json to template with an each loop

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am doing something wrong with backbone and underscore to echo some data in a template.

I have this php file: (test.php)

```
<?php
echo '{"data1":"test 1","data2":"test 2"}';
?>
```

And this template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="tpl-hello-backbone">
    <% _.each(messageView, function(messageView) { %>
        <%= kroeg %> 
        <%= locatie %>
    <% }); %>
</script>
```

This is my backbone file:

```
var MessageModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot : 'test.php'
});

var MessageView = Backbone.View.extend({

    template:_.template($('#tpl-hello-backbone').html()),

    render:function (eventName) {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});

var messageModel = new MessageModel();
var messageView = new MessageView({model:messageModel});
messageModel.fetch({
    success: function () {
        $('#msg').html(messageView.render().el);
    }
});
```

Now for some reason this echo's:

```
 test 2 test 1 test 2 test 1 test 2 test 1 test 2 test 1
```

so 4 times instead of 1.

And also when I make the json longer like this:

```
<?php
echo '{"kroeg":"test 1","locatie":"test 2"},{"kroeg":"test 1","locatie":"test 2"}';
?>
```

It echo's nothing at all. What am I doing wrong. I think I dont understand some stuff but I cant find what.

Hope anyone can help me out!

Greetings,
Merijn de Klerk

Comment: Why you iterate object? You need just output `<%= kroeg %> <%= locatie %>`

Comment: yeah I know. But as I explain in the post I also want it to work with multiple inputs

Answer (score 1):

Your template will work properly if you pass to `this.template()` a JSON object as follows:
`$(this.el).html(this.template({'messageView':[{'kroeg':'test 1','locatie':'test 2'},{'kroeg':'test 5','locatie':'test 6'}]}));`

That is, `_.each()` method expects messageView to be an array:

```
<script type="text/template" id="tpl-hello-backbone">
    <% _.each(messageView, function(messageView) { %>
        <%= messageView.kroeg %> 
        <%= messageView.locatie %>
    <% }); %>
</script>
```

Comment: Hmm yeah that sounds logical. Aldo it still isnt wokring. I dont get an error aswell..

Answer (score 0):

First problem in `each`: it iterate `messageView` keys, thats why output repeats.

So you have to replace

```
<% _.each(messageView, function(messageView) { %>
    <%= kroeg %> 
    <%= locatie %>
<% }); %>
```

With

```
<%= kroeg %> 
<%= locatie %>
```

About "longer json". You are trying to render **Collection**. You need to send data from PHP as array

```
<?php
    echo '[{"kroeg":"test 1","locatie":"test 2"},{"kroeg":"test 1","locatie":"test 2"}]';
?>
```

and create class for collection

```
var MessageCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MessageModel
});
```

instance it, fetch and [render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959879/render-a-backbone-js-collection)