# When to Render a Model and When to Render a Collection - Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am still learning about Backbone.js and I am not sure what the advantages and disadvantages are between rending a `model` one at a time versus rendering the `collection`.

I have seen examples where they render a `model` one at a time. For example:

```
//in parent view    
var view = new SectionView({model: section}); 

this.$("#section-list").append(view.render().el);



//in child view, render()

this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
```

With a template like:

```
<script type="text/template" id="section-template">
       <section class="view" id=section-<%- id %>>
                <label><%- height %></label>
                <label><%- color %></label>
                <label><%- id %></label>
                <button class="destroy">Delete</button>
       </section>
</script>
```

However, I have also seen examples where they render the entire `collection` such as this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959879/render-a-backbone-js-collection).

Much appreciated if someone could tell me when to use and what their advantages/disadvantages are.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't render models or collections, you render views. Views usually contain one model, or one collection, or less commonly some mixture of both. So the real question is should the view be associated with a model or a collection? The answer should come naturally.

Say you have an application involved with libraries. You have a `book` model, a `books` collection, so consequently you'll end up with a `book` view and a `books` view. The `books` view should be named more semantically, such as `bookshelf` view. When you render `bookshelf` view, you iterate through its `books` collection and assign each `book` model to a new `book` view, then render the view. The `bookshelf` view gets populated with `book` views.

A common pattern i see is a single view that acts as a container for sub views. The container view is associated with a collection, while the sub views are associated with models. The container view is rendered, which results in each model in the collection being rendered.

Comment: Thanks, Eric. Let's say I have a panel using jQuery UI dialog and it has an add button, slider, etc in it, does the panel need to be a view as well? Thanks.

Comment: Yes it makes sense for that panel to be a view. Backbone view's act as containers for smaller widgets. Generally, views are functionally discrete parts of your app. So making the add button or a slider a separate view would be overkill.